# How do you sort an HTML drop down by the Option text, not the value?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, sorting, drop-down-menu

When a user clicks a button, I'm loading extra genres into an HTML dropdown using jquery. I'd like to order the drop down in alphabetical order of the option text, not the value.

My php genre array looks like

```
$genres = array (0=>"All", 200=>"Pop", 201=>"Classic Rock", ...etc
```

The key numbers are loaded as the values in the drop down, while the text fills the options.

And my jquery

```
$.each(json, function(val, text)
{                   
    options[options.length] = new Option(text,val);
});
```

That displays in the drop down

```
All
Pop
Classic Rock
```

ie not in alphabetical order

My first plan was to sort the array in php, but on testing, even if the array is

```
 $genres = array (0=>"All", 201=>"Classic Rock", 200=>"Pop", ...etc
```

the drop down still displays

```
All
Pop
Classic Rock
```

How do I force it to order it in the order that it receives the json?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add a example of your json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like,

```
$(function(){
    var options = $("#select-box-id option");
    options.sort(function(a,b) {
        if (a.text > b.text) return 1; // .text for text comparison
        else if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
        else return 0
    });
    $("#select-box-id").html(options );
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/j35jM/)

Comment: I will try this now Rohan. Cheers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that your code worked fantastically Rohan - cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if the sorting is done in the server side (Or so I feel).

PHP has a couple of methods that let you sort based on `KEY` - `(ksort)` or `value` - `(asort)`

You could do this to your array :-

```
$genres = array (0=>"All", 200=>"Pop", 201=>"Classic Rock", ...etc
$stortedgeneres=$genres;
asort($stortedgeneres);
```

Then you can use your JavaScript on this array ($sortedgeneres) to loop through as before.

References:- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought too, but even when it's sorted by the option text on the server side, jquery seems to build the drop down according to the key values.